# Dealing with JFET parameter spread in voltage controlled resistor configuration

Tags: transistors, jfet

So I need to make a voltage controlled resistor to control a Q factor in RLC resonator, I'm using a P-channel JFET for this and I can't choose a JFET because datasheets show huge I<sub>DSS</sub> and V<sub>GS</sub> spread. Are there any ways to deal with this spread and make I<sub>DSS</sub> and V<sub>GS</sub> more controlled and determined? I need <5% resistance precision.

[image]

Comment: One way is to use feedback to control the gate voltage so you get the effect you need.  Other possibilities are digital pots, switched resistor networks, or screening JFETs.

Comment: what is your operating frequency and max signal amplitude?

Comment: @user287001 control signal is 3 V 40 Hz max, signal passing through JFET is 5V 30 MHz max

Comment: @JohnD what do you mean by "screening JFETs"? Shielding? What effect will shielding have on JFETs?

Comment: You might look into the H11F1 opto-coupler with a JFET output, designed for isolated analog control. Then the issue becomes the LED drive current, as high as 30 mA to saturate the JFET.

Comment: By screening I mean getting the manufacturer to sell you only JFETs within the tolerance you require. Alternately, you could buy a large quantity and test them yourself.  Semiconductor manufacturers don't like to screen, but if you want to buy enough of them and pay a premium you might be able to make a deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5V signal => forget it. Acting resistor is possible when the signal amplitude is say 1% of the pinch off voltage. 5V causes serious distortion.

To stay in truth, there's one trick to reduce the distortion (=feed the signal to the gate, too) but is it effective enough - do some simulations. You can found the trick from here: https://www.vishay.com/docs/70598/70598.pdf

Unfortunately you must still calibrate the R vs Control voltage for the used fet individual.

Another way: There are light dependent resistors which have only few pF self-capacitance. Check, if you can use one. Let a led illuminate the LDR and adjust LED's current. 40Hz control signal can be acceptably slow.

You can have easily linear resistance vs control voltage, if you put 2 leds in series, one illuminates LDR1 and the other illuminates LDR2. Then you have an opamp control circuit which forces the led current to cause the wanted resistance. Only have quite equal LDRs and leds.